# How can I turn off receiving SMS (not iMessages) on os x mavericks?

Tags: macos, messages, sms

Is there any way to turn off receiving SMS on Mavericks but still get iMessages? I find it a security flaw for SMS code login for secure websites, if somebody gains access to my computer they could also login to these sites.

Comment: SMS Handoff, the feature you are referring to, is not available on Mavericks. Also, if someone has physical access to your computer with malicious intent, I think you probably have bigger issues than just them logging into a website.

Comment: There is no SMS in iMessages. It uses the iMessage server to send messages (same like Skype). The SMS is a cellular feature (phone to phone), where the text message goes to the Cellular provider. So what about the security problem?

Answer (score 1):

SMS Handoff is not a feature on Mavericks, it needs Yosemite to function
[Thanks to @tubedogg for the confirmation]

To enable it you would start from your iPhone…
Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding - then add your computer from the list by switching on.

That will send a code to the computer, which you then enter on your phone to confirm the function - afaik, Mavericks will never receive that number, only Yosemite.

Switching off is
Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding again & simply turn off forwarding that computer.

Comment: You're correct, SMS Handoff does not work on Mavericks, only Yosemite.